# How to take Test Run ID from Jenkins using selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, report

How to take Test Run ID from Jenkins using selenium and Java.

Currently i`m using Extent Reports tool with Jenkins , Selenium and Java. Which generate reports after every test run.
But the problem is: Every test run It overwrites itself.
And i want to store test results instead of overwriting them.

Storing by date or time is a bad idea. 
How i can Take Build # From Jenkins and Attach 
it to

```
htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("/Users/admin/"+jenkinsBuildNumber+"extent.html");
```

Extent report. That every test run will generate Unique Report which will be stored and i can easily track them by checking Jenkins Test Case run #.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Jenkins environment variable  ${BUILD_NUMBER}

```
final String jenkinsBuildNumber= System.getenv("BUILD_NUMBER");
Reporter=newExtentHtmlReporter("/Users/admin/"+jenkinsBuildNumber+"extent.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can publish the reports generated by the Extent Reports tool in Jenkins.

Use [HTML Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin) in Post Build Actions.

By default, only the most recent HTML report will be saved, but if you'd like to be able to view HTML reports for each past build, select "Keep past HTML reports."